# Has winning by exactly an innings ever happened in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics

It's an interesting thing because it must be awfully rare, to say the least. This is for the whole of first-class cricket, by the way, not just Test cricket.

Comment: what do you mean by exactly an innings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible. Suppose the following happens:

- Team A score 100 all out
- Team B score 200 all out
- Team A score 100 all out

Team B will need to score 1 run in their second innings to win. If they are all dismissed for 0 runs (of course very unlikely), then the match is a tie. So they need to go out and bat to get that 1 run, at which point they will have won by 10 (or maybe 9, or 8...) wickets.

Had team A scored only 99 in the second innings, then Team B would have won by an innings and 1 run, and had they scored 101, Team B would have to score 2 to win. There is now way to "win by exactly an innings".

The case of runs being tied after the third innings has [happened in five test matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;innings_number=4;orderby=start;result=1;runsmax2=1;runsmin2=1;runsval2=runs;template=results;type=team;view=innings), most recently between [West Indies and India in 1983](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/16959/scorecard/63338/west-indies-vs-india-4th-test-india-tour-of-west-indies-1982-83/). None of the teams batting last had any difficulty in getting the required run to win the match.